# Overload operator +

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Simple question: I have a class simple_fraction and want to overload operator "+". Complilator returns error "operator + local function definition is illegal.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class simple_fraction {
private:
    int numerator; //числитель
int denominator; //знаменатель
public:
    simple_fraction(int numerator, int denominator) {

    //определение основных математических операций для простой дроби
    double operator+ (double val) { return number + val; } //сложение
}}

int main()
{
simple_fraction fr(2, 3);
double sum = fr + 10; //сумма
}
```

what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
simple_fraction(int numerator, int denominator) {

   //определение основных математических операций для простой дроби
   double operator+ (double val) { return number + val; } //сложение
}}
```

which makes the `operator+` function a local function inside the constructor, which is not allowed. You need to finish the constructor definition before the `operator+` function. And you also need to correct the operand inside the `operator+`

```
simple_fraction(int numerator, int denominator) : numerator(numerator),
                                                  denominator(denominator){}

double operator+ (double val) { return numerator + val; }
```

**PS**

That implementation of `operator+` does not sound right. Perhaps you meant:

```
double operator+ (double val) { return 1.0*numerator/denominator + val; }
```